# "In which" vs "of which" in a sentence refereing to activities

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases

Is using "of which" in the following sentence correct? can anyone tell me why it is correct and can we use "in which" instead of "of which"?

> I have taken the statistic course of which I passed with distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of or in.

Would you say "I passed of the statistics course" or "I passed in the statistics course"?

The verb "pass" is transitative and takes a direct object with no preposition:  "I passed the statistics course".

The pronoun "which" refers to "the statistics course, and so it isn't allowed to have a preposition in this case.

> ... the statistics course, which I passed...

(Statistics is always plural, a comma also needed for this non-restrictive relative clause, and you might consider if the context requires "a statistics course" or "the".)

Comment: if I want to use earned instead of passed, can I say: "I have taken the statistics course of which I earned A+."

Comment: No. "I have taken the course and passed it with a mark/grade of A+."